# alternative of koalas in pyspark? use dataframe in sql statement databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

My goal is to use the `df` in the SQL statement like below

creating `df`

```
 df = spark.readStream.format("delta") \
      .option("readChangeFeed", "true") \
      .table("mdp_prd.bronze.nrq_customerassetproperty_autoloader_nodups")
```

using this `df` in `sql` statement

```
%sql

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test_test as 
Select *
from {df}
```

I have find the solution in this [article](https://gbamezai.medium.com/azure-databricks-run-sql-commands-on-dataframe-ba85d89fc3fc#:%7E:text=So%20naturally%20when%20I%20learnt,pandas%20API%20on%20Apache%20Spark.) by using the `koalas` module which provides a drop-in replacement for pandas(above `sql` will work if I import koalas). But I worry about using koalas as I think it will decrease the processing time and I find efficient using pandas package in databricks when I can use pyspark.

Any other alternatives or work arounds to this?

Comment: What operations do you want to perform on that data?

Comment: this is something that will be used in the `def` which will be passed in the `foreachBach` of Autoloader later. Also, `def` will have some `merge` operation too.

Comment: More: I have used autolaoder to incrementaly load the data into staging/bronze layer. Now goal is to move the data incrementaly from bronze to silver layer but before doing so I need to do some manipulations on  the raw data, I have enabled the change feed feature on the tables. Then I `df = spark.readStream.format("delta").option("readChangeFeed", "true") `   and creating the tem_view from this. and this temp_view is used in the `Select .... From temp_view`.  but I also face the other problem  as select statement may include joins in it and Join between streaming Df not supported

Comment: most probably you don't need to use change data feed for your work - just do a normal streaming from delta.

Comment: will not it scan entire bronze table then? my goal is to dont scan entire table and only look at/move the changed feed data into silver

Comment: it will scan on first run, and then it will process only new versions

Comment: yeah,  that I dont want. I want to already scan changed feed and process that  one. Also, before processing I need to do some joins on iteself and receving the error that  Join between streaming Df not supported. Any idea how can I approach to this?